# Site turned module doesn't make Ajax requests anymore and gives error 'Access Denied'. Only in IE

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke

I have a small ASP.NET website which makes Ajax calls to a Web API web service (on another domain, CORS is allowed, headers are all set) using jQuery.

I tested it in both Chrome and IE10 and in both browsers the stand-alone site runs perfectly fine. The next thing I had to do was to turn the site into a DotNetNuke module. This was fairly easy to accomplish and when I tested it with Chrome the module worked and all Ajax requests were made. But when I run the same page in IE10 every Ajax request made by the module returns with the error message 'Access Denied'.

When I take a look in Fiddler I notice that IE doesn't even makes the Ajax requests.

I know there are several questions like this to be found on Stackoverflow, but I feel that their situation compared to mine is a bit different since Ajax works fine when I run the site without DotNetNuke in IE. Still I tried to make the same request using the code below, but I get exactly the same error and just like with jQuery Ajax there is no request to be found in Fiddler. Visual Studio throws the 'Access Denied' error when I do xdr.Open.

```
    if (window.XDomainRequest) {
// Use Microsoft XDR
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
xdr.open("get", "http://localhost:59390/api/controller/depots");
xdr.onload = function () {
    // XDomainRequest doesn't provide responseXml, so if you need it:
    var dom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    dom.async = false;
    dom.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
};
xdr.send();
}
```

Has any one an idea how this is possible and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check , if you DotNetNuke site is not running in Compatibility Mode. try adding the custom header from web.config  as below

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I run the site in compability mode (using the IE dev tools to switch). I also appended the header you gave but still nothing. When we have both the service and the DNN site with the module running on the same domain with just different ports it suddenly works. This is fine for our situation. But still one wonders...

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix this by any other way than putting the web service on the same domain as the DNN site runs on. And then it work as expected. But it is still strange that the site is able to pull the data using CORS ajax without any problems in IE if it doesn't run as a DNN module.